# How to filter a std::map keys using lamda expression in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I had map which consit of date as a key and some bytes as values in std::map<std::string, std::string>.
For Example

```
std::map<std::string , std::string> mapval = {{"2020-09-24", "1024"}, {"2020-09-25", "1024"},{"2020-09-26", "1024"},
    {"2020-09-27", "1024"},{"2020-09-28", "1024"}};
```

can I retrieve the keys only from the given range of date like if I want the data for three days from current date so I will fetch only "2020-09-24", "2020-09-25"and {"2020-09-26", "1024"}. i want a generic one where I have start date and end date and I will filter the value within that range and other value I will erase.
is it possible ?

Comment: Take a look at `std::remove_if()`

Comment: If you want a contiguous range of elements, you can find the iterator to the first and last elements to get an inclusive range. Otherwise you need to generate a list yourself.

Comment: But the challenge how to add a predicate which iterate the range of date between start and end. Any example if you can just give....it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but perhaps this will be close:

```
mapval = std::map<std::string , std::string>(
    mapval.lower_bound(start_date),
    mapval.upper_bound(end_date));
```

This would keep elements of `mapval` whose keys fall into the range between `start_date` and `end_date` (inclusive), and remove all others.